How can I point my domain to my NextJS app?
I operate an Apache server running Alma Linux, equipped with cPanel/WHM, hosting multiple websites on various subdomains. I aim to use my primary domain with my  Next.js application, which is already developed and deployed on port 3000 of the server.
What steps can I take, either through cPanel or command line interface, to achieve this?
Things I've tried:

Modifying the .htaccess file
Storing the NextJs project files in the root of the public directory on the server.
adding the port number in the package.json file to force it to use my default port for the server.

